# ¿Como hacer select dinámico con Ajax?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Estoy trabajando con 2 select, el segundo debería depender del dato que se seleccione en el primero. No he logrado hacerlo porque estoy un poco perdida en cómo funciona Ajax.

aquí dejo como estoy cargando el primer combo

```js
<select name='eq' id='eq'>
<?php
 $sq = "select * from EQUIPO";
 $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sq);

 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
echo "<option value=".$row['ID_EQUIPO'].">".$row['NOM_EQUIPO']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Para poderte ayudar envia el codigo de Ajax que has hecho, tabla que se consultara para armar el segundo select y la conexion a la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el evento change para que cuando se cambie el valor del primer select realice la petición ajax para cargar el segundo select

ejemplo:
en javascript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>//se requiere 

$(document).on('change','#eq', function(){
    var id=$(this).val();//obtengo el valor seleccionado
    $.ajax({  
        url : 'getsegundoselect.php',   
        data : { id : id },
        type : 'GET',
        //dataType : 'json',//si se requiere obtener un json
        success : function(res) {
          $("#idSegundoSelect").html(res);
        },    
        error : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('un problema');
        },
        complete : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Petición realizada');
        }
    });
});
```

en html

```
<select name='eq' id='eq'>
<?php
    $sq = "select * from EQUIPO";
    $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sq);

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<option value=".$row['ID_EQUIPO'].">".$row['NOM_EQUIPO']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name='idSegundoSelect' id='idSegundoSelect'>
</select>
```

en php para cargar segundo select, notase que en este puse tabla como ejemplo

```
<?php
   $id=$_GET["id"];//si se requiere el id enviado para su consulta
    $sq = "select * from tabla";
    $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sq);
    $result="";
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
     $result.="<option value=".$row['ID'].">".$row['Nombre']."</option>";
    }
 echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias, me sirvió mucho pero no he podido arreglar que en el segundo select, me muestra sólo los espacios, no el texto xdd

Comment: no entendí bien tu duda, el segundo solo te muestra espacios?, si es asi puede ser por los acentos agregar echo utf8_encode($result)

Comment: sí, el segundo select solo me muestra los espacios, en la cantidad que correspondería... Pero el texto que debería mostrar, no lo muestra

Comment: revisa con echo utf8_encode($result) o verifica si estas obteniendo bien el valor del campo $row['Nombre'] según como lo hayas definido tu campo